# Display image from stream in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I have a requirement to display an image in between a component in an ASP.NET MVC web application.

I have the stream of the image as a string.

I tried the following:

1. Convert the string to the stream
2. Converting the stream to image using `Image.FromStream` from the `Drawing` namespace

The step 2 throws an error

> Error: Parameter is not valid

Please suggest a proper way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

***Update***:
I went with another approach.
I wrote the stream in the file system and used its URL to display the image.